# Scroll bar disappears when modal closes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quote, modal

I have this modal on `Quote` object which works as I expect. The problem is that before opening the modal, I have scroll bar on the `Quote` object main page, but when I open the modal and then I close it, the scroll bar in the main `Quote` page is disappeared !

This is my style:

```
<style>
    .slds-modal__container {
        max-width: 850px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-height: 630px !important;
        height: 120% !important;
    }
</style>
```

And this is my hide modal action:

```
hideModal : function(component) {
    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
    dismissActionPanel.fire();
}
```

Before opening the modal:

[image]

After opening and closing the modal:

[image]

Comment: Try to remove `max-height` from css and check.

Comment: @TusharSharma unfortunately didn't work.